# Is there a way to target specific file in Box app on IOS through box:// url scheme?

Tags: box-api

Box:// seems to open the app, however I am not able to discern how to target a specific file.

Answer (score 0):

Currently we don't have support for this, but it is a great idea that we'll consider for our roadmap.

Comment: I would also like to have this feature, we have some requirement from our client. I would like to know if I send the full url from the backend say Box://myfolder/doc/adc.doc and user taps on that will he be able to go directly to the doc.

Answer (score 0):

We actually do support this. The best way to add this integration into your app is to use our OneCloud AppToApp framework (additional information available here http://developers.box.com/the-box-sdk-for-onecloud-on-ios/)

This is easy using the app-to-app framework. You just need to call BoxAppToAppAPI's `sendFileDownloadRequestToApplication:withMetaData:` if you want an app to go to a particular file and in Box's case download/preview it.

To make it go to the Box app you can simply pass in `[BoxAppToAppApplication BoxApplication]` in the first parameter.

As for the metadata parameter, you can create it with BoxAppToAppFileMetadata's `appToAppFileMetadataWithFileName:fileExtension:folderPath:mimeType:fileID:folderPathByID:exportToken:username:`
Assuming your app already integrates with the Box API via the SDK or otherwise, it should be able to get all of that information easily.

If the mimeType is not known, nil can be passed in. Also, nil can be passed in for the `exportToken` if the file was not exported out of the Box app (with the AppToApp framework, a roundtrip scenario is also supported where the user starts in the Box app, picks a file to view/edit/etc in your app, and then sends it back to Box to upload). So if it's not a round-trip, it's just a one-way from your app to Box, use nil for the `exportToken`.

Before doing this, you can also check if the Box app is installed by checking for `[[BoxAppToAppApplication BoxApplication] isInstalled]`.

Below is a fictional example (the values are made up):

```
BoxAppToAppFileMetadata *metadata = [BoxAppToAppFileMetadata appToAppFileMetadataWithFileName:@"fileName"
                                                                                fileExtension:@"png"
                                                                                   folderPath:@"All Files/Folder1"
                                                                                     mimeType:nil
                                                                                       fileID:[NSNumber numberWithLongLong:123456]
                                                                               folderPathByID:@"0/12345"
                                                                                  exportToken:nil
                                                                                     username:@"username@email.com"]
BoxAppToAppStatus status = [BoxAppToAppAPI sendFileDownloadRequestToApplication:[BoxAppToAppApplication BoxApplication]
                                                                   withMetaData:metadata];
```